# Minimization of difference

Tags: optimization, sorting

Given two lists $\{a_1,a_2, \ldots,a_n\}$ and $\{b_1,b_2, \ldots,b_n\}$ and you can rearrange elements in each list individually. You have to rearrange element in it in such a way value of **S** is minimized. 
$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^n \,\left| a_i-b_i\right|  
$$
What should be strategy of rearrangement of individual lists ?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Problem statement modified.

Comment: Why wouldn't sorting both lists in increasing order work?

Comment: Try: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations#Solving_Methods

Comment: Will sorting both work ? I was not able to prove it formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove that sorting works for lists containing two elements: $\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $\{b_1,b_2\}$. Thus, you'll have proved that if $a_1\leq a_2$ and $b_1 \leq b_2$, then $|a_1-b_1|+|a_2-b_2| \leq |a_1-b_2|+|a_2-b_1|$. This proves it for lists of size $n$ as well - if there is an inverted pair, the SAD (sum of absolute differences) only decreases when you exchange elements of list b to remove inverted pairs.